# Correct Generalization for Adair Equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, proteins, chemical-engineering

[image]

I know how to derive the Adair Equation for n binding sites the long way, writing n+1 mini equations and linking them to relate all sub $K_b$ values to $K_{b-intrinsic}$.

Tried to find a general formula for the adair equation and found different versions online.

If I raise $K_i$ to the ith power, does that make the generalization correct?

Thanks - studying for an exam.